# Google Maps API Remove Step "Numbers" from Directions Output

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API to display directions.

The directions output each step with numbers. Is it possible to remove these numbers?

[image]

I used inspector to find a unique identifier for the step numbers but unfortunately there is only the parent class ".adp-substep".

Is there a way to remove the actual step numbers from the directions?

Comment: I tried looking for a way to target jstcache since thats the only unique thing I see.. looks like that is data that only displays on browser output though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

CSS

```
td.adp-substep:nth-child(2){
    display:none;
}
```